# I am having trouble booting into Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, mount

As of last night i have not been able to boot into my OS. 
Whenever I do I get a blank command line similar to if there is NO OS installed.

I believe it is due to where it is mounted, when I originally mounted it i set it at `/`.

But now it is set to mount at:

`/mnt/99324b15-036c-4d4b-9c05-f5b006f41198`

and the devise identifies as:

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/99324b15-036c-4d4b-9c05-f5b006f41198`

Comment: You can try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if this fails, put the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I believe it is due to where it is mounted, when I originally mounted it i set it at "[/]" but now it is set to mount at "[/mnt/99324b15-036c-4d4b-9c05-f5b006f41198]"***

Your comment about where you mounted it is confused. It's all relative. Your root device probably has UUID "99324b15-036c-4d4b-9c05-f5b006f41198". When your boot process is correct, whatever device contains your root partition is shown to you as /

If you haven't been goofing with boot related stuff, I'd take a look at your bios settings. Maybe your boot device is set to something else? It sounds like you're booting in to something, is there a USB installer still attached to your machine and you're booting off of that?

*EDIT: Added Boot Repair notes below.*

## Boot Repair

You should [follow the steps to run Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Here are the key steps:

1. Boot off of your USB Installer
2. *sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair*
3. *sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list*
4. *sudo apt-get update*
5. *sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)*

Comment: I've tried booting directly into the HDD to make sure, but thats still what i get, currently i have a USB attached because I'm running the trial off of it

Comment: Great, congratulations.